# why use different pointer types?

Tags: c, pointers, kernel

In a lot of standard open source code, I see in various places different pointer types being used like :

```
uint32 fooHash (uint8 *str, uint32 len)
```

What I don't get is the following:
- Why would you want to declare int as uint32, uint8? 
  All of this would run in the userspace itself, so why not just leave as uint itself?
  Wouldn't portability be an issue later on?

- Also, if you want to run the opensource code on 32bit system, why have a pointer as
  uint8 *ptr?

Comment: Because of `ptr + 1` (or `ptr[1]`). Internally, the compiler must know how many bytes to advance from `ptr` (1 byte for `uint8*`, 4 bytes for `uint32*`, 42 bytes for `struct fortytwo*`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, if you want to run the opensource code on 32bit system, why have a pointer as uint8 *ptr?

`uint8_t` is the size of the thing the pointer *points to*, not the size of the pointer itself; the type of the *expression* `*ptr` is `uint8_t`.  The type of the *object* `ptr` is `uint8_t *`, which is as big as the system needs it to be (32 bits, 64 bits, whatever).

The base type matters when computing pointer arithmetic.  Given a pointer declaration

```
T *p;
```

the expression `p + i` evaluates to the address of the `i`'th *element* of type `T` after `p`.  If `T` is `int`, then `p + i` gives us the address of the `i`'th integer following `p`.  If `T` is `struct humongous`, then `p + i` gives us the address of the `i`'th humongous structure following `p`.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  uint8_t  *p0 = (uint8_t *)  0x00004000;
  uint32_t *p1 = (uint32_t *) 0x00004000;

  printf("p0 = %p, (p0 + 1) = %p\n", (void *) p0, (void *)(p0 + 1));
  printf("p1 = %p, (p1 + 1) = %p\n", (void *) p1, (void *)(p1 + 1));

  return 0;
}
```

yields the output

```
p0 = 0x4000, (p0 + 1) = 0x4001
p1 = 0x4000, (p1 + 1) = 0x4004
```

Pointers need not all be the same size, or have the same representation.  For example, in a Harvard architecture, instructions and data are stored in separate areas of memory and may have different sized busses, so object pointers (`int *`, `char *`, `float *`) may be one size (say 8 bits) and function pointers (`int (*foo)(void)`) may be a different size (say 16 bits).  Similarly, on a word-addressed architecture, a `char *` may be a couple of bits wider than other pointer types to specify an offset into the word.

Comment: thanks but I have another basic question...can't believe I am asking something so basic but I am really confused.                                       so with uint8_t *p0 case, we have p0 = 0x4000 and (p0 +1 ) = 0x4001 on a 32bit architecture. Now, p0 and (p0+1) are supposed to differ by 1byte or 8 bits. but 0x4000 would be 0100 0000 0000 0000 and 0x4001 would be 0100 0000 0000 0001   I am failing to understand how they differ by 8 bits or 1 byte : ( : ( What am I missing here?

Comment: @user999755: Remember that 0x4000 and 0x4001 are *addresses*, and that x86 is a *byte-addressed* architecture.  0x4000 is the address of one byte, and 0x4001 is the address of the next byte.

Answer (score 5):

The type of the pointer refers to the datatype it contains, not the size of the pointer itself.  All pointers are in fact the same size. ([*] But see the comments below)

If you have a `uint8*`, then the pointer refers to an array of `uint8` values.  This is not the same as `uint32*`, which refers to an array of `uint32` values.

To answer the other side of your question...  The reason that these types are made explicit is because not all compilers agree on the size of an `int`.  It's a portability thing.

Comment: "All pointers are in fact the same size." - in practice, mostly (but not always). But the Standard doesn't specify that.

Comment: Pointers to data rarely differ in size (but as H2CO3 said, this isn't specified by standard). Pointers to data and pointers to function (or member function) however...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I am used to thinking of all pointers being the same size as `void*`...  Maybe that's misguided. =)

Answer (score 2):

Not all data is meant to be stored as `signed int`. A `uint8*` is useful for many purposes: strings, binary data (eg a network packet or a piece of a file).

Sometimes you just need uint8 because the range of values you are going to store there resides in `[0,256[`.

Don't forget that we are not talking about the *type of the pointer* but about the *type of the pointed data*. A pointer is a pointer (which will be of correct size according to the architecture) whatever type it points to.

Comment: Is there value in using a uint8 as opposed to a char?

Comment: If you are storing unsigned values there there is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the hardware and compiler that you are using.

if you just use an int you can get different sizes. You can also get different sizes on unix vs windows.

All that is required of the compiler is from C99 standard

```
sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) < sizeof(long long)
```

Here is the int type sizes (bits) for Windows platforms:

```
Type           C99 Minimum     Windows 32bit
char           8               8
short          16              16
int            16              32
long           32              32
long long      64              64
```

you should take a look at

the following are guaranteed to be the size they they are named for

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
int8_t
```